# A logic question on binary variables

Tags: optics, visible-light, electronics, electrical-engineering, sensor

I recently purchased some nightlights with sensors. The sensor will make sure the nightlight will only be tuned on in a dark environment. Let's assume the sensor is binary, ON or OFF.

Here is the question come to my mind, what will happen if we put 2 night lights in one dark room that they can trigger each other's sensor?

It can not be both OFF, and cannot be both ON. If one ON and one OFF, which one should be ON?

Then, how about I put a mirror on one nightlight, that its light on its sensor? Should it be ON or OFF? Both seems to be wrong.

Is this a math question or logic question or physics question? I am new to the community, please help.

EDIT: Thanks very much for the answers. If we assume they have exact timing and they blink, then what's the frequency?

Comment: Seems to me that you are in the best position to answer that question.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that each sensor sees only the light from the other night light, and assuming that each night lights is bright enough to reliably trigger the other's sensor, then you have discovered a configuration that computer engineers call a "flip-flop".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29

It has another name, "bistable multivibrator."  "Bistable" because it has two stable states.  "Mutivibrator" because...  I forget.  Maybe Google knows.

Anyway, it has two stable states.  Either lamp can be on, and the other one will be off, and it will remain that way until you force it to change (e.g., by shining a flashlight on the sensor of the one that's on.)

Electronic flip-flop circuits are the basis of high-speed computer memory (a.k.a., "Static RAM") and computer "register" circuits.

When you first power it up, it could power up in either state.  Depending on the characteristics of the sensors and the lamps, it could also power up in a so-called "metastable" state, which will last for an indeterminate amount of time.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Metastability

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. What you have arrived on is a classic conundrum. Let me make my argument clear through a few scenarios.

First, is the light from the nightlight bright enough to affect itself? I mean, if the light is turned on, won't the environment become bright again and hence and trigger a change? I am assuming it does not work that way.

Second, let us assume that there are two nightlights now. If it is dark, both will be turned on at the same time. Seeing it is not that dark immediately after it is turned on, it will switch back off. When it is switched back off, it will detect no light and turn on. In short, the lights will blink.

Same case with the mirror scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming they are bright enough to affect the other light, then, it will depend upon if they have exactly identical timing or not.

Theoretically, with identical timing and mechanism, they should blink.

Even a tiny fraction of a second difference will be important. If one light switches on a fraction earlier, the other one will stay switched off. The mechanism with which they actually act could introduce some timing difference and the difference may become significant enough may be a few blinks down.

In case of single light and mirror, it surely will blink assuming reflected light is bright enough to turn it off.